# Series of strcmp() calls at the start of simple C++ program

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, ltrace

I have a simple C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
        std::cout << "Hello\n";
        return 0;
}
```

I was playing with "scratchbox" - cross compilation platform that I use in order to compile applications for ARM platform. I run it on my Nokia N900 phone.

While investigating some performance problems I noticed several calls to strcmp() in the beginning. I used "ltrace" to trace the library calls and when I run it on a target (my cell phone) a see series of calls to strcmp() which is now making me curious - what is the purpose of these calls?

```
20:06 user@MaemoBox:~$ ltrace test
__libc_start_main(61732, 1, 0xbed66634, 345616, 345612 <unfinished ...>
__errno_location()                                                                                 = 0x4001d3b0
strrchr("test", '/')                                                                               = NULL
getuid()                                                                                           = 29999
bsearch("test", 0x00055966, 146, 1, 0x0000ed38 <unfinished ...>
strcmp("test", "mv")                                                                               = 7
strcmp("test", "sort")                                                                             = 1
strcmp("test", "tr")                                                                               = -13
strcmp("test", "sysctl")                                                                           = 1
strcmp("test", "test")                                                                             = 0
<... bsearch resumed> )                                                                            = 0x000559e2
```

Comment: If I were to guess, I would say that the code is compiled for a debugger.  Re-compile as a release build, and you may see those calls disappear.

Comment: Hmm, I have not used any debugging options explicitly. I have recompiled same file using gcc -O3 option - "ltrace" shows exactly same sequence of strcmp() calls.

Comment: @Alexi Try `ltrace ./test` (as suggested in Alok's answer below)

Comment: Yes it is me being stupid :-) I was looking at ltrace of /usr/bin/test which is because /usr/bin comes first on my PATH. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure, but could it be that `test` actually is the [system `test` command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_%28Unix%29), and not the program you wrote?  This could happen for example if `$PATH` does not contain `.`, the current directory.  And given that it is a small platform, all `test`, `mv`, etc., might actually be just one executable, which emulates the correct program by figuring out what it is called as?  See [Busybox](http://www.busybox.net/) for example.

If that is the case, all the `strcmp()` are basically the executable trying to figure out what it is being run as.  Solution: name your program something other than `test`, or run `ltrace <path_to_your_executable>/test`.

The `strrchr()` call before the `strcmp()` calls suggests strongly that it is trying to extract the executable "basename", without the directory.  In which case, running it as `"./test"` won't probably help, so you should rename it to something that's unique.  (Just a guess, again.)

I could be wrong, since there is theoretically, the platform can do anything when it runs an executable.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with `scratchbox`, but if it is similar to `busybox`, I assume it is comparing its called name (`argv[0]`) with common Unix utilities/functionalities that it provides. If none match, it passes control to your code.

Comment: Application is compiled in scratchbox environment however traces I have obtained when running binary on target (cell phone) itself NOT in scratchbox. Lukily for me I can run some tools directly on my phone given that it is running just a small distro of Linux (Maemo 5).